# Is this a simple or a compound sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, compounds

I was reading [an article about types of sentences](http://www2.ivcc.edu/rambo/eng1001/sentences.htm). It seemed very easy to understand simple and compounds at first, but there is something wrong with the examples! Please read the following sentence:

> Mary and Samantha arrived at the bus station early but waited until
>   noon for the bus.

As you can see there is a coordinative conjunction "but" in this sentence and I belive that this is compound. But in the written text it was classified as a simple sentence! The writer mentioned that "arrived" and "waited" is a compound verb, while the whole sentence is considered to be a simple sentence.

Comment: I would agree with you. It's a compound sentence.

Comment: @user178049 Actually I think I was wrong because `waited until noon for the bus.` lacks a subject and so it is not an independed clause. So the whole sentence could be a simple!

Comment: It does have a subject, which is understood rather than obvious. The subject is "Mary and Samantha".

Comment: Why is it important to know what this particular sentence might be called?  Is it just curiosity or is it actually *useful* information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mary and Samantha arrived at the bus station early but waited until noon for the bus.

This is a simple sentence with a compound subject and a compound predicate. It is not a compound sentence because there is only one independent clause.

Answer (score 1):

> *Mary and Samantha* [*arrived at the bus station early*] *but* [*waited
>   until noon for the bus*].

"Mary and Samantha is the subject. The bracketed elements are a coordination of verb phrases, which together with the coordinator "but" form the predicate of the sentence.

There is only one independent clause, the sentence as a whole, and hence this qualifies as a simple sentence.